# How to have scrcpy run automatically on wake from suspend?

Tags: bash, scripting, systemd, suspend

I am on LinuxLite 6.0 and I have been trying to run `scrcpy` on wake from suspend. I've tried many things but haven't found the solution.

Here's what I have (`/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/example.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..." >> /tmp/test
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..." >> /tmp/test
    exec scrcpy
    ;;
esac
```

- `echo` returns feedback but it doesn't run `scrcpy`
- I have also tried running another script through this script but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Does scrcpy need X11/Xorg? If it does, it won't work this way, it needs $DISPLAY and Xauth.

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I find out?